# Issue with description from php to csv

Tags: php, csv

I use php to generate a csv file like this:

```
<?php 
function myfunction() {
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.csv');

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputs( $output, "\xEF\xBB\xBF" );

    foreach (rows as $row) {
      $description=$this->FixDescription($row['Description']);
      $id = $row['id'];
      $myrow .= $id . ',' . $description ."\n";
}

      fputcsv($output, mb_convert_encoding($myrow, 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8'));
      fclose($output);
}
   public function FixDescription($descr){
    $d = html_entity_decode($descr, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $d = htmlspecialchars_decode($d);
    $d = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $d);
    $d = strip_tags($d);
    $d = str_replace('&','_',$d);
    return $d;
  }
?>
```

When i download the generated file i get some rows correctly but for some rows description breaks and leaves blank rows and then prints and generally create a mess in my csv file. Any ideas of how not to break the content inside description field?

Comment: Stop trying to pass strings to `fputcsv()`.... it works with an array argument, not with a string that you've mangled already

Comment: Ok can you please suggest another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace

```
$myrow .= $id . ',' . $description ."\n";
```

with

```
fputcsv($output, array($id,$description);
```

You wouldn't need these lines anymore

```
fputs( $output, "\xEF\xBB\xBF" );
fputcsv($output, mb_convert_encoding($myrow, 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: I get wrong encoding and also i have the same result

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
foreach (rows as $row) {
    $description=$this->FixDescription($row['Description']);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $myrow .= $id . ',' . $description ."\n";
}

fputcsv($output, mb_convert_encoding($myrow, 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8'));
```

with

```
foreach (rows as $row) {
    $description = $this->FixDescription($row['Description']);
    $description = mb_convert_encoding($description, 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8');
    $id = $row['id'];
    $myrow = [$id, $description];
    fputcsv($output, $myrow);
}
```

Comment: I get wrong encoding and also i have the same result

Comment: Then what is the encoding of your data?

Answer (score 0):

In my FixDescription function it was added the following line before return:

```
$d = preg_replace('/\r\n/','',$d);
```

This way ENTER is replaced and description is in one line